# Side nav bar disappear when click on link

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have created Side nav bar using HTML and CSS and I have given a link but when click on the link my side nav bar disappear even though the position of nav bar is fixed. Can any one help me to figure out the issue?? The complete new page is displaying when click on the link without the side nav bar I have  created.

My code:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 400px;
  /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">Certificates</a><br/><br/>
  <a href="dup.html">Plan</a><br/><br/>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Example</h2>
  <p>This sidenav is always shown.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you referring to the Plan link? Does that page have the same sidebar?

Comment: @isherwood yes...I am refering to plan link....no it doesn't have same side bar

Comment: Then why would you expect one to be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<a>` tag leads to a different page which doesn't include your sidebar HTML. Assuming we are working strictly with a static site, you'll need to just copy the HTML for your sidebar and paste that into the `dup.html` file.

Comment: Can we make dynamic....like keeping sidenav in only in one page but showing other page also

Answer (score 1):

Does your dup.html even have elements with the class that you made to look like a sidenav?
Your elements -->

```
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">Certificates</a><br/><br/>
  <a href="dup.html">Plan</a><br/><br/>
</div>
```

are the sidenav if you don't have them on your other page there is no sidenav to be displayed.

Comment: Oh that means I need to put same sidenav in my other page also

Comment: @Micky exactly just copy that codesnippet into the other file named dup.html. Sorry for the hard to understand answer :D I'm not that good in explaining and english

Comment: @Micky to your comment on the other answer cause I still cannot comment on other posts: yes you can do that you would need a CMS for that

Comment: No worries..your explaination and english are understandable